# Confirming that Santiago de Cuba to Dominican Republic route exists

Tags: air-travel, planning, routes, cuba, caribbean

I finish my Cuba trip in Santiago de Cuba and need to connect to South America. As of now, my two options, according to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com), are

1. Get back to Havana, Cuba, then take a flight to my next destination, or
2. Go from Santiago de Cuba, Cuba to Santo Domingo, Dominican Republic, then connect to my next destination.

According to [Cubana's](http://www.cubana.cu/home/) site, the Santiago de Cuba to Santo Domingo route exists, but according to [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.net), no flight information comes up for that. This worries me as I would like to make sure that this route exists. I know this may seem trivial, but because I have to pay for these tickets in cash and can't book online or in advance (US citizen), I want to be sure since I plan on booking a connecting flight from Santo Domingo. But if the Santiago de Cuba to Santo Domingo, Dominican Republic route doesn't exist, then I need to change my connecting flight.

Can someone help confirm this from a reliable source?

Comment: Skyscanner doesn't list every airline, nor every flight for every airline. I'm just curious - is there a reason you don't think Cubana is reliable enough a source, given Rome2Rio also backs it up?

Comment: Every flight search engine tries to bluff users into believing they cover all flights on all routes with all airlines. But it's hogwash. I always use three or four flight search engines when looking for tricky stuff.

Comment: @MarkMayo It's not that I don't think it's reliable. It's that I've never used it and that I'll be going to Cuba. So I just want to be sure for peace of mind. :)

Answer (score 6):

There is only one definite confirmation and that is the flight. If you are on it, then it exists. Now, you might want to know if it will probably occur in advance and for that, the second best option is the airline itself.

- You checked Cubana's site which is a good step.
- To do better, call them and ask about that flight when whether it runs a the particular date or dates you are interested in. Some routes are seasonal, so they exist but do not occur for months.

Back to my intro above. I have been booked on a flight and checked-in with a valid boarding pass even already printed and seat assigned yet the flight did not run. I got an email 2 hours before the departure saying it was cancelled. When I called, they said they cancelled my flight for that day. The next day, the same thing happened and they cancelled it for the next 3 days. It just was not getting full enough. Instead I took a 3 hour bus to the next closest airport to get a new flight. They charged me for the change but then I got a 100% refund back to my credit card a few weeks later and an apology.